# Elasticsearch what are the formulas to calculate total shards

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch and I found out the standard way to calculate total shards is
total shards=primary * (1+replicas)

So in this example

```
PUT /my_index/_settings
{
  "number_of_shards": 3,
  "number_of_replicas": 2
}
```

The answer gives as 9.

```
total shards=primary * (1+replicas)
9=3 * (1+2)
```

May I know that alternatively can I use below formula too since it gives the same answer as 9?

```
total shards= number_of_shards + (number_of_shards * number_of_replicas)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a math question and has nothing to do with ES.

```
primary * (1 + replica) = primary + (primary * replica)
```

Comment: your answer didn't clarify my query though , thank you anyway.

Comment: Is anyone else who are knowledgeable with the tool, please share the thoughts . Thank you.

Comment: @SahilGupta is right, the two equations you give are exactly the same, i.e. `a * (1 + b) ≡ (a * 1) + (a * b) ≡ a + (a * b)`, by virtue of [distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property)

Comment: @Val Thank you ,  SahilGupta thank you too , I accepted your answer as well.